# How to add button inside a tag href

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wanted to have  tag with href and image inside, i have added some css and my  tag looks like a square with href link, and now i want to add clickable button inside  tag, button with javascript onClick. I have add it but when i'm clicking button  href link clicked not my js function, anybody can help me with this?

Comment: Can you show us the code you've tried so far? Debugging without any code is quite a difficult endeavor.

Comment: please show some code so we can better assist you

Comment: Add ur code to js fiddle and share with us

Answer (score 1):

`a` tag is the only element that can have an attribute of `href`. I've made a small sample:

HTML:

```
<a href="#">Click me</a>
```

CSS:

```
a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 0;
  background: red;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font: 17px Arial;
}
```

But for the `onClick` event, how would you like it to be executed?